# C# - Create JSON array of objects from Dictionary

Tags: c#, json

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this, I just haven't been able to figure it out yet.

I need to return an array of objects in `JSON` (which I'm completely new to). The structure should look like the following:

```
{"files": [
  {
    "picture1.jpg": true
  },
  {
    "picture2.jpg": true
  }
]}
```

I thought I could do this by using a `Dictionary` but that doesn't seem to work the way I want it to either. Below is what I have so far and what the output is. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

This is what I have in `C#`:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> DeleteImages(List<string> ids)
{
    var files = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        var file = await _fileService.GetByIdAsync(id);
        if (await AzureStorage.DeleteFile(file))
        {
            files.Add(file.Name, true)
        }
    }

    return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(files));
}
```

The problem is that this returns the following:

```
{
    "picture1.jpg": true,
    "picture2.jpg": true
}
```

Comment: This is the same problem as in [your last post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51935125/1070452)

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, it is the same problem. However, I went and tried a few more things that came to mind to see if I could solve it first. I posted this one with more details describing what my exact issue was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution will provide exactly what you are looking for.  The real key is creating an intermediate object to hold the entries you are looking for rather than simply placing the files in a Dictionary.  The other complication is that you are really looking for a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary contains one file name/deleted entry.

The file collection class:

```
public class FileCollection
{
    [JsonProperty("files")]
    public List<Dictionary<string, bool>> Files { get; set; }

    public FileCollection()
    {
        Files = new List<Dictionary<string, bool>>();
    }
}
```

Your existing logic, modified to use the new collection class:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> DeleteImages(List<string> ids)
{
    var files = new FileCollection();

    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        var file = await _fileService.GetByIdAsync(id);
        if (await AzureStorage.DeleteFile(file))
        {
            files.Files.Add(new Dictionary<string, bool> { { file.Name, true } });
        }
    }

    return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(files));
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Only thing I had to change was I needed to add in an extra set of `{}` in order to get it to build properly. `files.Files.Add(new Dictionary<string, bool> { { file.Name, true } });`